# getting linked table path with tabledef.connect

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been trying to get the path to a linked table. I am looping thru the tables. it works one the first loop but not on the 2nd loop. it returns "".

Ive tried several different ways, calling the table by name or by number. the code originally comes from Neville Turbit. Neville's code calls the table by name, but I could not get that to work.

```
Public Function GetLinkedDBName(TableName As String)

Dim tblTable As TableDef
Dim strReturn As String
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo Error_NoTable ' Handles table not found

'---------------------------------------------------------------
'
i = 0
On Error GoTo Error_GetLinkedDBName ' Normal error handling

For Each tblTable In db.TableDefs
    If tblTable.Name = TableName Then
        strReturn = tblTable.Connect

        strReturn = db.TableDefs(i).Connect
        Exit For
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Next tblTable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a loop:

```
Public Function GetLinkedDBName(TableName As String) As String

    Dim strReturn As String

    On Error Resume Next    ' Handles table not found

    strReturn = CurrentDb.TableDefs(TableName).Connect

    GetLinkedDBName = strReturn

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, Ive tried the 
"strReturn = CurrentDb.TableDefs(TableName).Connect" but without success. I checked that the table exists in the local properties and also the typed the table name in directly. the routine does not error.

Answer (score 1):

This is my modification from Gustav's.

CurrentDb.TableDefs(TableName).Connect command will returns a string like this:

"MS Access;PWD=p455w0rd;DATABASE=D:\Database\MyDatabase.accdb"

The string above contains 3 information and parted by ";" char.
You need to split this information and iterate through it to get specific one which contain database path.

I am not sure if different version of ms access will return exact elements and with exact order of information in return string. So i compare the first 9 character with "DATABASE=" to get the index of array returns by Split command and get path name from it.

```
Public Function getLinkedDBName(TableName As String) As String

    Dim infos, info, i As Integer 'infos and info declared as Variant
    i = -1

    On Error Resume Next    ' Handles table not found

    'split into infos array
    infos = Split(CurrentDb.TableDefs(TableName).Connect, ";")
    
    'iterate through infos to get index of array (i)
    For Each info In infos
        i = i + 1
        If StrComp(Left(info, 9), "DATABASE=") = 0 Then Exit For
    Next info

    'get path name from array value and return the path name
    getLinkedDBName = Right(infos(i), Len(infos(i)) - 9)

End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).